# Unit Test syntax errors still allow you to build on local

Tags: unit-testing, compilation, azure-devops, commit, team-explorer

We use Azure DevOps as our repository and our solution has multiple projects; including a web application, a SQL server database project, a unit test project, and multiple class libraries. When committing changes, the build will fail in Azure DevOps, because it fails to compile the Unit Test project. The problem, is locally you can still launch your solution even with Unit Test syntax errors. If you look at your Error List you would notice them, but is there any way for either - forcing the solution launch to fail with Unit Test syntax errors, or prevent Team Explorer commits if there are any errors listed in the Error List?

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no such a way to do this. On one hand, Visual studio build helps you to find the problem in your codes, if you can't launch when there is error, how do you find and fix it? On the other hand, I think it is better to build your solution and fix the error before you commit。

Besides,  there is no way to prevent committing you code, since the commit command just captures a snapshot of the project's currently staged changes, it does nothing with your source codes.

Comment: The primary problem is that if unit tests have syntax errors, you can still build the project. The only way you would ever notice, is if you just check the error list every time before you commit. I need some sort of way to force a check for errors, either on build or on commit. If not, it fails every artifact build attempt in the repository. Only then do we see it was just a unit test that never had it's parameters updated, even though we could build locally without issue.

Comment: I am sorry it seems can't be implemented